# Show that $\pi_1$ of this cover is a normal subgroup with index $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, normal-subgroups, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

> We are given a cover of the figure eight-
> [image]
> Show that $\pi_1$ of this cover is a normal subgroup with index $\mathbb{Z}$.

I have shown that the given cover is regular, hence the image of its fundamental group is normal in $G=\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$. If the red and blue loops are labelled $a$ and $b$, then it seems that the fundamental group of the cover is $H = \langle b^kab^{-k}\rangle$. It seems that its cosets are precisely $b^nH$; I can show that any word in $a,b$ can be written in this form.

But, I can't formalize my ideas.

---

Edit: I now see that $H=\langle a\rangle$. So, words in $G/H$ all look like $b^n$ which makes the idea of "number of $b$'s" in a given word from $G$ well defined; this number will identify the coset $b^nH$ the word belongs to.

Comment: I *think* one way to see that $b^nH$ is a distinct coset from $H$ is to count the number of $b$’s in each word. The number of $b$’s in every word of $H$ would be $0$. You might have to do some shenanigans showing that the “number of $b$’s” in a word is actually well-defined, though. With this in mind, a clean way of finding the index of $H$ might be to show that it contains every element with zero $b$’s, then apply first isomorphism to the $b$ counting homomorphism. (I haven’t thought through this very thoroughly, so I apologize if any of this is nonsense.)

Comment: I imagine proving $H$ is of the form you give would just involve showing that those are the generators of the covering space. You could use van Kampen probably.

Comment: @Frank I now see that $H=\langle a\rangle$. So, words in $G/H$ all look like $b^n$ which makes the idea of "number of $b$'s" well defined.